# Amazon S3 map url to backend server like Apache's <Location /api> ProxyPass

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Is there a way to map a URL to a backend server in S3. I am not looking for redirects, but something on the lines of Apache's Location directive with ProxyPass.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

```
<Location /api/>
    ProxyPass http://api.myec2instance.com/
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. S3 is the **Simple** Storage Service. It won't handle proxying requests for you like this.